# Как правильно описать две связи к одной и той же таблице в одной сущности (многие-ко-многим)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Имеется такие модели

```
class StipendOrder(Base, LoggedEntity):
    __tablename__ = 'stipend_order'

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'Приказы на стипендию'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = column_property(Column(Boolean, default=True),
                             info={'verbose_name': 'Активен?'})

    #stype_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stipend_type.id'), nullable=False)
    stype = relationship('StipendType', secondary='stipend_order_stypes_rel', order_by="StipendType.id", uselist=False, info={'verbose_name': 'Тип стипендий'})  # Stype
    stypes = relationship('StipendType', secondary='stipend_order_stypes_rel', order_by="StipendType.id", uselist=True, info={'verbose_name': 'Типы стипендий'})  # Stypes


class StipendOrderStypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stipend_order_stypes_rel'

    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stipend_order.id'), primary_key=True)
    order = relationship('StipendOrder')

    stype_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stipend_type.id'), primary_key=True)
    stype = relationship('StipendType')
```

Модель приказа (StipendOrder) имеет связь с secondary-таблицей которая задает связь многие-ко-многим с Типами стипендий (StipendType)

Остались огрызки связи многие-к-одному ввиде колонки stype_id в StipendOrder (всмысле такой колонки сейчас в StipendOrder нет, просто так раньше было)

Мне хотелось для обратной совместимости оставить связь с единственным типом стипендии (первой из многих) которая раньше задавалась

```
stype_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('stipend_type.id'), nullable=False)
stype = relationship('StipendType', info={'verbose_name': 'Тип стипендий'})  # Stype
```

Теперь она задана

```
stype = relationship('StipendType', secondary='stipend_order_stypes_rel', order_by="StipendType.id", uselist=False, info={'verbose_name': 'Тип стипендий'})  # Stype
```

Получается в приказе одновременно определены две связи stype - с возвратом 1 значения (uselist=False)
и stypes - с возвратом полного списка типов стипендий (uselist=True)

Все вроде работало хорошо на выводе на изменении обектов, но когда у меня происходят удаления происходят подобные ошибки

> DELETE statement on table 'stipend_order_stypes_rel' expected to
>   delete 5 row(s); Only 4 were matched.

stypes - связь связана с 5 типами стипендий, видимо мое задание и uselist=False связи исключает 5-1 одну связь из 5 и алхимия при удалении дочерних объектов ломается

Вопрос - можно ли как-то этом все исправить? Задать допустим в рилейшне stype - что он игнорируется алхимией в отслеживании при удалениях? Или вообще убрать этот "дублирующий рилейшн" и создать какое-то свойство-обертку для stypes которое возвращает первый элемент?

Или просто лучший вариант переписать те старые использования кода в проекте типа order.stype для логики "Нескольких типов стипендии в приказе" ?